# Flutter AppDelegate.m file under the Runner folder doesn't exist for ios config

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, keycloak

I would like to integrate

> simple_auth_flutter: ^2.0.11

into my flutter project. This should run via keycloak ...

In the installation it says that I have to modify the AppDelegate.m for ios like this:

```
#include "AppDelegate.h"
#include "GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h"
#import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
#import <simple_auth_flutter/SimpleAuthFlutterPlugin.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  [GeneratedPluginRegistrant registerWithRegistry:self];
  // Override point for customization after application launch.
  return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options{
    return [SimpleAuthFlutterPlugin checkUrl:url];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation{
    return [SimpleAuthFlutterPlugin checkUrl:url];
}

@end
```

but my problem is, there doesn't exist this file in runner folder.

There is only the AppDelegate.swift
it look like this

```
import UIKit
import Flutter

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

I guess I'll have to work with that. How do I do that properly?

Comment: I'm guessing you created a new app iOS app using SwiftUI instead of Storyboard and Objective-C?  That or you're using the Xcode beta?

I'm on Xcode 12.5.1 and it has the option to build an Objective C AppDelegate.m file.

Comment: I also have the 12.5.1 version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `AppDelegate.m` is used by iOS Projects that primarily use the Objective-C  language. iOS Project using the newer Swift language have a `AppDelegate.swift` file instead. They are identical in functionality.

You might be able to use the following code to complete the integration.

```swift
import UIKit
import Flutter

// Don't forget to add this!
import simple_auth_flutter

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
        return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }

    // Add this
    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        return SimpleAuthFlutterPlugin.check(url)
    }

    // Then, add this  
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
        return SimpleAuthFlutterPlugin.check(url)
    }
}
```

Notice that the function names are identical between the Objective-C and Swift versions. Since your iOS project is already using `.swift` files, it is already setup to use something called a [Bridging Header](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/importing_objective-c_into_swift).

This allows code written in Objective-C (in this case, iOS code in the simple_auth_flutter package) to be used from Swift.

Because of this, you can import the required "simple_auth_flutter" module and start using its Objective-C methods from Swift without additional setup.

##### References

[Simple Auth Code for iOS](https://github.com/Clancey/simple_auth/issues/149)

[Related Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66266152/simple-auth-flutter-on-ios-appdelegate-swift-import-change-fails-to-start)